# Поиск кратчайшего пути из точки A в B, проходящего через точку С. Алгоритмы.

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы, поиск-пути

Как реализовать поиск кратчайшего пути из точки A в B, проходящего через точку С в невзвешенном графе.

Можно ли для такого использовать волновой алгоритм? И как его потребуется изменить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью поиска в ширину ([BFS](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/bfs)) будем находить кратчайшее расстояние между двумя вершинами.

Тогда решение вашей задачи сводится к поиску кратчайшего расстояния между вершинами A и С, и нахождением кратчайшего расстояния от C к B. Т.е. надо будет запустить BFS два раза, от вершины А и от вершины C.

Comment: Благодарю.